# Careers Profile Edit Relocation Layout Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On my Stack Overflow Careers profile, I was entering places I was willing to relocate to and decided to try to enter "Northeast Ohio" as a general area:

[image: Entering Northeast Ohio]

---

After I was done typing I clicked the "I have the legal right to work" checkbox and all hell broke loose:

[image: I broke the web]

---

This was using the edge version of Chrome on Windows 7.   In Firefox and IE9 it looks better but the error message is still looks "off":

[image: IE9]

Comment: Yeah. This one is weird. Working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: the error message now displays correctly.